# Articulation Points Algorithm causing infinite loop

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I'm trying to identify the nodes in a graph which would cause said graph to become disconnected if an node was removed using an iterative articulation point algorithm, seen below:

```
public class ArticulationPointsFinder {
    Node start; 
    ArrayList<Node> articulationPoints = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public ArticulationPointsFinder(Node start) {

        // Set the start point and mark the depth as 0
        this.start = start;
        start.articulationDepth(0);

        int numberOfRootSubtrees = 0;

        // foreach neighbour of the start
        for (Node neighbour : start.neighbouringNodes()) {
            if (neighbour.articulationDepth() == null) {
                this.iterativeArticulation(neighbour, start);
                numberOfRootSubtrees++;
            }
        }

        // Add the root node the articulation points
        if (numberOfRootSubtrees > 1) {
            this.articulationPoints.add(start);
        }

        // Cleanup depth on nodes
    }

    private void iterativeArticulation(Node currentNode, Node root) {
        Stack<ArticulationPointNode> nodeStack = new Stack<ArticulationPointNode>();

        nodeStack.push(new ArticulationPointNode(currentNode, 1, new ArticulationPointNode(root, 0, null, 0, null), 0, null));

        while (!nodeStack.isEmpty()) {
            ArticulationPointNode elem = nodeStack.peek();
            Node node = elem.node();

            // Initialize
            if (elem.parent().children() == null) {
                node.articulationDepth(elem.reach());
                elem.reach(elem.parent().depth());
                elem.parent().children(new LinkedList<Node>());

                // Check neighbours
                for(Node neighbour : node.neighbouringNodes()) {
                    if (!elem.parent().node().equals(neighbour)) {
                        elem.parent().children().add(neighbour);
                    }
                }
            // Nodes to process 
            } else if (!elem.parent().children().isEmpty()) {               

                while (!elem.parent().children().isEmpty()) {
                    Node child = elem.parent().children().poll();

                    if (child.articulationDepth() != null) {
                        elem.reach(Math.min(elem.reach(), child.articulationDepth()));
                    } else {
                        nodeStack.push(new ArticulationPointNode(child, node.articulationDepth() + 1, elem, 0, null));
                    }
                }   

            // Lastly   
            } else {
                if (!node.equals(currentNode)) {
                    if (elem.reach() >= elem.parent().depth()) {
                        this.articulationPoints.add(elem.parent().node());
                    }
                    elem.parent().reach(Math.min(elem.parent().reach(), elem.reach()));
                    nodeStack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my POJO that is stored in the stack:

```
public class ArticulationPointNode {
    private Node currentNode;
    private int reach, depth;
    private ArticulationPointNode parent;
    private Queue<Node> children;

    public ArticulationPointNode(Node currentNode, int reach, ArticulationPointNode parent, int depth, Queue<Node> children) {
        this.currentNode = currentNode;
        this.reach = reach;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.depth = depth;
        this.children = children;
    }

    public Node node() {
        return this.currentNode;
    }

    public int reach() {
        return this.reach;
    }

    public void reach(int reach) {
        this.reach = reach;
    }

    public ArticulationPointNode parent() {
        return this.parent;
    }   

    public int depth() {
        return this.depth;
    }

    public Queue<Node> children() {
        return this.children;
    }

    public void children(Queue<Node> queue) {
        this.children = queue;
    }
}
```

At the moment, this is causing an infinite loop when run on a small dataset, and stepping through, I cannot easily identify the reason why it's iterating infinitely. Thoughts?

Comment: "The nodes in a graph which would cause said graph to become disconnected if an edge was removed" doesn't make much sense to me.  Surely whether removing an edge causes its graph to become disconnected is a characteristic of that *edge*, not properly a characteristic of any vertex (not even of the vertices connected by said edge).

Comment: Sorry. If a **node** was removed.

Comment: Does your graph contain any self edges?

Comment: It is not obvious to me what the problem is, and, frankly, I have difficulty following your code because of stylistic issues.  Even though I know the algorithm, your unconventional and ambiguous names for property accessors, vague variable and method names (e.g. `elem`, `parent`, `child`), extensive use of method chaining, and too-similar class names (distinct kinds of `Node` with completely different roles) all contribute to a continual sense of "what is this, again?" as I try to follow.  Perhaps they even confuse you, too.

Comment: Apologies. This is the first time I have attempted this algorithm. I appreciate you at least trying to help, regardless. Thanks.

Comment: I do find it suspicious, however, that all information about algorithm state appears to be bound up in the `ArticulationPointNode` objects, including *global* state, such as whether a given graph node has yet been visited.  You would not be searching for articulation nodes if you assumed your graph was a tree, so it has to be prepared to handle loops.

Comment: Inasmuch as the recursive version of the algorithm is easier to describe and (I think) easier to implement, you could consider first implementing that, and then converting it to an iterative implementation.  That has the advantage of making it very clear which data are associated with the recursive frames (these are the ones you need to track on a stack) and which are global.

Comment: I'll take your advice and approach it from the recursive variant first; thank you also for the constructive criticism. Cheers.